# Is there a way to disconnect or sandbox an instance network interface

Tags: network-programming, google-compute-engine

I am looking for how I can take an existing instance and either change its network "connection" to a sandboxed network (which is easy enough to create since each project supports up to 5 networks) or start the instance with no network interface at all and just use console access. Alternatively, what is the recommended process for doing forensic investigation into an instance that is suspected to be running processes or services that should not be communicating with other instances in the project or any external address? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can leave instances without a public IP address. Instances created this way will not accessible by machines outside your project.

Have a look at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances-and-network) concerning IPs.

You may also need to set up a [NAT gateway](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#natgateway) so instances can communicate with ouside machines.

You can use [forwarding rules](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/network/forwarding-rules) to discard packets from/to an instance in combination with [routing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#instancerouting).

Comment: I have an existing VM that has been used as a publicly-available system. It was exhibiting questionable behavior so we shut it down. I want to power it up for analysis without it being able to connect to any other systems.

This is equivalent to the old-school forensic process of disconnecting the ethernet cables from a physical system and investigating what is running on it via the local console.

Thanks

Comment: Make a snapshot of the disk. Create a VM without external IPs in a different network than your project Use the snapshot as a base for the boot disk of the new instance above. This article has some tips: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting